# TransformException after updating gradle version

Tags: android, gradle, autobahn

Am using the following library Autobahn for web sockets usage in my Android project.

When am using the old gradle version 1.3.0, am not encountering any issues in building & running the app, whereas
when i update the gradle version to 1.5.0, am encountering the following issue.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: de/tavendo/autobahn/ByteBufferInputStream.class

I have tried the below options already
1. multiDexEnabled is set to true in gradle file.
2. gradlew clean is also done, along with clean build.

Any other suggestions to resolve this issue would be great.

Regards,
Dinesh Kumar G

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have two editions of this library, such as one as a plain JAR and one via an artifact from a repository?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, i just have the jar added to the libs folder, i dont have any artifacts of this library from repo added in gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jitpack.io/#tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/v0.5.2) is a interesting way to add Autoban build to gradle. Try to remove your jar and add this in your build file.

Comment: Am still getting into same error, whether i add the jar file or add the library as a dependency they way you specified.               Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: de/tavendo/autobahn/WebSocketMessage$Message.class

Comment: Have you tried gradle 2.0? Also, have you updated Android Studio to version 2?

Comment: yes my studio version is 2.0 & gradle is 2.0 as well. I've removed all the duplicate libs.Then i got into the following error File1: .gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.7\3bc2efad5ceb9e24e44f731d4282b5df3ea6d23f\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7.jar
        File2: \gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.7\2dd41e7570f5c73e63a6a1311671a60c817e1989\jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar.  But the issue is i couldnt find where these error is coming from, so i excluded them in gradle file packagingOptions { exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'}